# How to find an embedded platform?

Tags: embedded, hardware

I am new to the locating hardware side of embedded programming and so after being completely overwhelmed with all the choices out there (pc104, custom boards, a zillion option for each board, volume discounts, devel kits, ahhh!!) I am asking here for some direction.

Basically, I must find a new motherboard and (most likely) re-implement the program logic.  Rewriting this in C/C++/Java/C#/Pascal/BASIC is not a problem for me.  so my real problem is finding the hardware.  This motherboard will have several other devices attached to it.  Here is a summary of what I need to do:

Required:

- 2 RS232 serial ports (one used all the time for primary UI, the second one not continuous)
- 1 modem (9600+ baud ok) [Modem will be in simultaneous use with only one of the serial port devices, so interrupt sharing with one serial port is OK, but not both]
- Minimum permanent/long term storage: Whatever O/S requires + 1 MB (executable) + 512 KB (Data files)
- RAM: Minimal, whatever the O/S requires plus maybe 1MB for executable.

Nice to have:

- USB port(s)
- Ethernet network port
- Wireless network

Implementation languages (any O/S I will adapt to):

- First choice Java/C# (Mono ok)
- Second choice is C/Pascal
- Third is BASIC

Ok, given all this, I am having a lot of trouble finding hardware that will support this that is low in cost.  Every manufacturer site I visit has a lot of options, and it's difficult to see if their offering will even satisfy my must-have requirements (for example they sometimes list 3 "serial ports", but it appears that only one of the three is RS232, for example, and don't mention what the other two are).  The #1 constraint is cost, #2 is size.

Can anyone help me with this?  This little task has left me thinking I should have gone for EE and not CS :-).

EDIT: A bit of background: This is a system currently in production, but the original programmer passed away, and the current hardware manufacturer cannot find hardware to run the (currently) DOS system, so I need to reimplement this in a modern platform.  I can only change the programming and the motherboard hardware.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com or chiphacker.com

Comment: I'm not trying to make a board/chip (I want off the shelf), nor is this a power user question. I thought embedded questions were ok here.

Comment: @gmagana: I think it really needs to be a *programming* question to be on SO. I suggest you use superuser.com for hardware/software questions and/or chiphacker.com for questions about embedded hardware.

Comment: Great answers so far, thank you.  I have also asked on ChipHacker.  Thanks Paul R for the suggestion.

Comment: I really don't know where to say to draw the line, but things of this nature are very relevant to programming and I think are perfectly fine here.  That said, I can see Paul R's POV as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest buying a cheap Atom Mini-ITX board, some of which come with multi - 4+ RS232 ports.

But with Serial->USB converters, this isn't really an issue.  Just get an Atom.  And if you have code, port your software to Linux.

Here is a link to a [Jetway Mini-Itx board](http://www.logicsupply.com/products/j7f2we_1g), and a link to a [4 port RS232 expansion module](http://www.logicsupply.com/products/ad4com) for it.  ~$170 total, some extra for memory, a disk, and a case and PSU.  $250-$300 total.

Now here is an [Intel Atom Board](http://www.logicsupply.com/products/boxd410pt) at $69 to which you could add flash storage instead of drives, and USB-serial converters for any data collection you need to do.

PC104 has a lot of value in maximizing the space used in 19" or 23" rackmount configurations - if you're not in that space, PC104 is a waste of your time and money, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me directly to the sources, great suggestions!

Comment: @gmagana Happy to help.  Atom is going to truly revolutionize embedded systems design, I think.  A whole system for $69?  Good luck!

Comment: I have used those VIA C7 chips before, and I was pleasantly surprised at the power I got for the price.

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer simply because you pointed me over to the perfect solution for me: A stock product made by a great company, at an absolutely unbeatable price (the Atom board).  I don't need to debug electronics I just need to make the MB work with the existing peripherals and power supply (which I think is compatible).  I think you just enabled me to deliver this thing on time! Thanks!

Comment: @gmagana: http://www.addonics.com/products/flash_memory_reader/adsacf.asp Here's a link to a plug in sata/CF adapter if you want to go the low-cost flash storage route.

Answer (score 3):

The [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/hardware) should have everything you need for $200 or so - it can run Linux so use whatever programming language you like.

Answer (score 2):

A 'modern' system will run DOS so long as it is x86, I suggest that you look at an industrial PC board from a supplier such as [Advantech](http://www.advantech.com/), your existing system may well run unchanged if it adheres to PC/DOS/BIOS standards.

That said if your original system runs on DOS, the chances are that you do not need the horsepower of a modern x86 system, and can save money by using a microcontroller board using something fairly ubiquitous such as an [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture).  Also if DOS was the OS, then you most likely do not need an OS at all, and could develop the system ["bare-metal"](http://www.state-machine.com/arm/Building_bare-metal_ARM_with_GNU.pdf).  The resources necessary just to support Linux are probably far greater than your existing application and OS together, and for little or no benefit unless you intend on extending the capability of the system considerably.

There are a number of resources available (free and commercial) for implementing a file system and USB on a bare-metal system or a system using a simple real-time kernel such as FreeRTOS or eCOS which have far smaller footprints than Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows embedded site ( http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/default.mspx )

has a lot of resources and links to hardware partners, distributors and development kits. There's even a "Spark" incubation project ( http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/community/spark/default.mspx )

What's also really nice about using windows ce is that it now supports Silverlight as a development environment.

Comment: Being a Windows guy, I would go for the embedded Windows, except that Windows CE takes time to learn/adapt, and it's not even clear that CE has a future, given the latest volatility I've been reading about Windows 7 phone not being compatible with CE and all that.  Last thing I want is to get out of an obsolete platform to get right into another one.  I will wait it out, and once Windows has their ducks in a row I may jump right into embedded Windows with this thing.  Thanks!

Comment: I find that a bit odd considering Phone 7, Kin, Sync, Xbox 360  and Courier are all running on CE6. I know the problem with Phone 6.* was that they branched from CE, which is why it fell flat.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the jetway boards / daughter cards that Chris mentioned with success for various projects from embedded control, my home router, my HTPC front end.

You didn't mention what the actual application was but if you need something more industrial due to temperature or moisture constraints i've found http://www.logicsupply.com/ to be a good resource for mini-itx systems that can take a beating.

A tip for these board is that given your minimal storage requirements, don't use a hard drive.  Use an IDE adapter for a compact flash card as the system storage or an SD card.  No moving parts is usually a big plus in these applications.  They also usually offer models with DC power input so you can use a laptop like or wall wart external supply which minimizes its final size.

This http://www.fit-pc.com/web/ is another option in the very small atom PC market, you'd likely need to use some USB converters to get to your desired connectivity.

The beagle board Paul mentioned is also a good choice, there are daughter cards for that as well that will add whatever ports you need and it has an on board SD card reader for whatever storage you need.  This is also a substantially lower power option vs the atom systems.

There are a ton of single board computers that would fit your needs.  When searching you'll normally find that they don't keep many interface connectors on the processor board itself but rather you need to look at the stackable daughter cards they offer which would provide whatever connections you need (RS-232, etc.).  This is often why you see just "serial port" in the description as the final physical layer for the serial port will be defined on the daughter card.

There are a ton of arm based development boards you could also use, to many to list, these are similar to the beagle board.  Googling for "System on module" is a good way to find many options.  These again are usually a module with the processor/ram/flash on 1 card and then offer various carrier boards which the module plugs into which will provide the various forms of connectivity you need.

In terms of development, the atom boards will likely be the easiest if your more familiar with x86 development.  ARM is strongly supported under linux though so there is little difficulty in getting these up and running.

Personally i would avoid windows for a headless design like your discussing, i rarely see a windows based embedded device that isn't just bad.

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at one of the boards in the Arduino line, in particular the [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega).  Very flexible boards at a low cost, and the Mega has enough I/O ports to do what you need it to do.  There is no on-chip modem, but you can connect to something like a Phillips PCD3312C over the I2C connector or you can find an Arduino add-on board (called a "shield") to give you modem functionality (or Bluetooth, ethernet, etc etc).  Also, these are very easy to connect to an external memory device (like a flash drive or an SD card) so you should have plenty of storage space.

For something more PC-like, look for an existing device that is powered by a VIA EPIA board.  There are lot of devices out there that use these (set-top boxes, edge routers, network security devices etc) that you can buy and re-program.  For example, I found a device that was supposed to be a network security device.  It came with the EPIA board, RAM, a hard drive, and a power supply. All I had to do was format the hard drive, install Linux (Debian had all necessary drivers already included), and I had a complete mini-computer ready to go.  It only cost me around $45 too (bought brand new, unopened on ebay).

**Update:** The particular device I found was an EdgeSecure i10 from Ingrian Networks.